# Strapi api not giving a response when registering user even though it was updated in the admin panel

Tags: node.js, postgresql, authentication, axios, strapi

I am using Strapi with postgres to register a new Strapi end user and I am using the following code to send a post request with the new user's credentials:

```
//...
  try {
    // encrypt the user password
    const encryptedUserPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local/register",
      {
        username,
        email: email.toLowerCase(),
        password: encryptedUserPassword,
      }
    );

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ message: ["Registration failed"], error: err });
  }

// ...
```

The problem that I am facing is that whenever I send the post request, the data is being successfully updated in the Strapi admin panel and eventually in the postgres database but **it is not returning a successful response and it continues to process until it throws an Axios error** even though the data is updated in my Strapi admin panel.

This is the **error** that I received when I send the post request to register a new user:

```
{
  "message": [
    "Registration failed"
  ],
  "error": {
    "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "config": {
      "transitional": {
        "silentJSONParsing": true,
        "forcedJSONParsing": true,
        "clarifyTimeoutError": false
      },
      "transformRequest": [
        null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
        null
      ],
      "timeout": 0,
      "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength": -1,
      "maxBodyLength": -1,
      "env": {},
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "axios/0.27.2",
        "Content-Length": 130
      },
      "method": "post",
      "url": "http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local/register",
      "data": "{\"username\":\"testuser04\",\"email\":\"testuser09@email.com\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$pqeADn.WL4BqHYpTonVl2.KYqoxtuJZyvdpgc659W90zmsu4Wo2jW\"}"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 400
  }
}
```

I am using the recommended Strapi node version `14.19.3` with the following `package.json` dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.2.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.2.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.2.3",
    "pg": "8.6.0"
  },
```

Could someone please help me or give me some tips on what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just resolved this problem. It turns out that just needed to set the default value for the email confirmation in the admin panel to false. Also, I needed to authorize my application to make requests directly to the API